# People should be educated not to downvote a question just because the answer is no

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have noticed that if I ask a question about something that is technically impossible, such that the answer is "no", it gets downvoted. But if the question is good, it shouldn't get downvoted just because of that.

I also suspect a specific user of downvoting my questions - even if the question is solid IMO. This happens in particular when the answer is no.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460347), to which the answer is no, provides an example of the problem, shows what I have tried before and is clear IMO.

Yet my question was downvoted (as usual).

In the guidance on downvoting, it should say not to do this.

Comment: Just because a question is solid in your opinion, doesn't mean it's the only opinion. That's the idea of voting. And if the answer is simply a curt/obvious "no", people are within their right to vote on the Q as not useful.

Comment: Separately from the topic of how users should vote on specific types of questions, I would remove any mention of specific users voting a certain way, as that's unprovable, unproductive and will result in a negative reaction to your post (in addition to any negative reaction it may receive due to the other content).

Comment: You're making some very strong claims of being able to mind read people. Yet I feel you cannot actually mind read. I'm looking at the question and feels there is no problem with the answer being "no" but the question just plain not making sense to be asked in the first place. "Can I eat the soup off my spoon before I even dip it in the bowl?" is sort of what you asked. And now you're concerned that the reason that got a downvote is because the answer is "No".

Comment: Also, you have no way to know how anyone votes, assuming otherwise will just lead one to make a fool of themselves. And as far as I can see from **public information** is that halfer committed the terrible "crime" of editing your post to more closely follow our guidelines.

Comment: The reason it's downvoted is because there's no context to help motivate why you want to do such a strange thing (access something before it exists), which usually suggests an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/233676#233676). The question reminds me of [George Carlin talking about pre-boarding](https://youtu.be/vdPy5Ikn7dw?si=e_kVtujXIw73xa8W&t=91). Many XY problem askers insist on you not caring about problem X and just giving them the gun so they can shoot themselves, but this is frustrating. I want to solve real problems, not presupposed solutions.

Comment: The issue isn't simply that the task cannot be performed; the issue is that **it does not make sense to expect** to be able to perform the task. As such, it does not form a **useful** question, and raises a strong suspicion of an XY problem. Of course you cannot modify the data before it has loaded, because "to load" means to make the data available (including for modification).

Comment: Just wait for the [new shiny](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f) upcoming *NonCausal.js* library (not to be [confused](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/causally#Usage_notes) with *NonCasual.js*).

Answer (score 32):

To be honest, the reason I'd downvote a question like this is that it very much as the texture of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

You're looking to do *something* kinda sneaky with the timings of parsing the DOM vs parsing the JavaScript, which...doesn't exactly work.  This gets worse depending on the browser you're using, with no guarantees of consistency between any of them; that is to say, a loading order of one browser may or may not be the same as another, or may or may not be the same as yet another.

Hell, does this event even exist??  How do you know you're not ready to load anything and you've transmitted the DOM for manipulation before it's parsed??  Like, *what*???

Hearing someone say "what are you really trying to do here" might sound condescending, but the reality is, we need to understand what it is you're trying to actually ***do*** before we can answer your question.  What you're describing as your attempted solution is ***confusing to us***, so we downvote to send that message.

Comment: "What you're describing as your attempted solution is confusing to us, so we downvote" - and also vote to close as needing details or clarity.